# write.table does not append information from extracted different csv files

Tags: r, append, write.table

I want to extract some values from set csv files and append them in a new csv file.
When I use write.table(append=T), the information does not get appended but gets overwritten.

```
for(Tsd in c(0.001))
{
  for(Fsd in c(2,5,10,15,20,30,60))
  {
    nameoffile <- paste("summary_out_T_",Tsd,"_F_",Fsd,"_2.csv",sep="")
    durdata <- read.csv(file = nameoffile, header=TRUE, sep=",")

    name2 <- paste("duration.csv", sep = "")
    file.create(name2)

    a=c("Fsd", "onSD")
    write.table(as.matrix(t(a)), sep = ",", name2, col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T)

    aa = c(Fsd, durdata[[16,14]])
    write.table(as.matrix(t(aa)), sep = ",", name2, col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T)
  }
}
```

The output file "duration.csv"
should have 8 lines

```
> Fsd onSD 
> 2   a
> 5   b
> 10  c
> 15  d
> 20  e    
> 30  f
> 60  g
```

instead it only has

```
> Fsd onSD
> 60  g
```

Is there something i am missing? shouldn't append=T take care of that?

Comment: Did you try `readr::write_csv`

Comment: I did, and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here: `file.create(name2)`: you are creating the file again and  overwriting.
Try

```
name2 <- paste("duration.csv", sep = "")
file.create(name2)


for(Tsd in c(0.001))
{
  for(Fsd in c(2,5,10,15,20,30,60))
  {
    nameoffile <- paste("summary_out_T_",Tsd,"_F_",Fsd,"_2.csv",sep="")
    durdata <- read.csv(file = nameoffile, header=TRUE, sep=",")

    a=c("Fsd", "onSD")
    write.table(as.matrix(t(a)), sep = ",", name2, col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T)

    aa = c(Fsd, durdata[[16,14]])
    write.table(as.matrix(t(aa)), sep = ",", name2, col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T)
  }
}
```